# mysql get result by colum name in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have inherited the a big table with a lot of columns that aren't in alphabetical order to work with.

It goes something like this:

```
---------------------------------
| g | c | e | d | f | h | a | b |
---------------------------------
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
---------------------------------
```

Here x is the field value:

I need help in trying to figure out how to return this:

```
---------------------------------
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
---------------------------------
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
---------------------------------
```

Using a select. 
For reasons out of my control I cannot change the master table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care if the columns are in alphabetical order?

Comment: This question makes no sense. You can choose the columns to select so select them in any order you want: `select a, b, c from table`

Comment: If information_schema didn't help you, why can't you order your columns in software?

Comment: I have 550 columns so I didn't want to type this out So what I ended up doing was: select all column_name from information schema in order. then I copied all the column names and pasted them in a select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps create view with desired order

```
    create view test.v as select a,b,c,d,e from table;
    select * from test.v;
```

Answer (score 2):

Mysql will return the columns in the order of the select statement, so just

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
FROM table
```